# Shield image on desktop application icon

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-10, desktop-application, elevated-privileges

I have a C# Desktop application (windows 10) that does not require administrator privileges to run. I've already removed the manifest file that existed, but even so, after installation, the icon displays an image of a shield, and when running it the credentials are required, what else could be causing this?

Comment: Try to run as administrator.

Answer (score 5):

> what else could be causing this?

The name. If it contains "setup", "install" or "update", Windows will add the icon if no manifest is available.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd835540(v=ws.10)) and look for "installer detection technology".

To remove it, add a manifest and define a privilege that does not require administrator, e.g. "asInvoker":

```
[...]
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" />
</requestedPrivileges>
```